# Is there a type for callback functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

[image]
The error says `Supplied parameter do not match any signature of call target`.
When I replace `Function` with `any` as the second parameter's type, the error disappears. But `any` is the same as no type, isn't there a suitable type for functions as parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `Function` (or `any`) you can use the following type for your `callback` parameter:

```
(ev: Event)=> any
```

This matches the type expected by `addEventListener`.

Here is the full function signature:

```
on(eventName: string, callback: (ev: Event)=> any, useCapture: boolean) : Dom.Element {
    //...
```

Comment: Ok. So it means the type is function with ev parameter of type Event that returns any?

Comment: Yes - although think of the return type as simply being very permissive. You can pass a function that returns void, or a string, or a number - whatever you like; *allow any return type*.